# sequence with pre-defined accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to create a sequence which has the following accumulation points; $\pi$, $e$, $100$.

Can I just say that, $n \geq 1$ ..?

$ a_n = \begin{cases} \pi-\frac{1}{n} &for&  n=0(3) \\
                        e+\frac{1}{n} &for&  n=1(3) \\
                        100+\frac{1^n}{n^2}  &for& n=2(3)
\end{cases}$

Comment: Sure.  Even more simply, leave off the $\frac 1n$ terms.

Comment: perfect, thank you